# Azure B2C Self-service password reset user flow returning undefined

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am using azure b2c for IAM and in that I have configured Sign up and sign in user flow for the website. In the user flow I have enabled Self-service password reset, which helped to use this user flow for forgot password journey as well.
[image]

When I try forgot password flow using unregistered email address, OTP is getting sent to that email address and OTP is getting verified as well but instead of getting message "An account could not be found for the provided user ID." I am getting undefined error message. This works fine if I use separate user flow for forgot password.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one Sign up and sign in user flow where I enabled ***Self-service password reset*** like below:

[image]

When I ran the above user flow, I got the screen with **`Forgot your password?`** like below:

[image]

After selecting **`Forgot your password?`**, I entered **unregistered** email and got code like below:

[image]

When I selected **Continue**, I got the ***same error*** as you like below:

[image]

> Note that, in a [sign-up and sign-in journey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow), only ***registered*** user can reset their own password by using **Forgot your password?** link. Make sure to **register** the user first before using that link.

So, I registered that user by selecting **`Sign up now`** option in user flow and entered details like below:

[image]

Now I ran the user flow again and selected **`Forgot your password?`** by entering the above **registered** email and it verified like below:

[image]

When I selected **Continue**, it took me to `Password Reset` page successfully like below:

[image]

You need to use **custom policies** to customize the error you got when ***unregistered*** user email is entered in **`Forgot password?`** link.

You can also collect your B2C logs with Application Insights. But this feature only supports **custom policies**, not user flows.

**Reference:**

[Troubleshoot custom policies with Application Insights - Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

Comment: Thank you Sridevi for confirming, I think Microsoft need to enhance this for user flows as showing undefined is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently fixed in v2.1.19 of the page templates (I have not tested myself).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout#self-asserted-page-selfasserted

> Handle Undefined Error message for existing user sign up